# QAbstractItemModel::beginResetModel()/endResetModel() emits 2 GridView.onCountChanged

Tags: gridview, qml, qt5

I have a QAbstractItemModel and refresh it with `beginResetModel()` (`elements` is specially prepared array with elements:

**Model.cpp**

```
void GridModel::loadModel(const QVector<const VisualElement*>& elements)
{    
    this->beginResetModel();
    if (!_elements.isEmpty()) {
        for (auto& i : _elements) {
            delete i;
        }
        _elements.clear();
    }

    _elements = elements;

    this->endResetModel();
}
```

This class connected to GridView in qml `context->setContextProperty("keyboardModel", _keyboardModel);`

**CustomGridView.qml**

```
GridView {
    id : inputPanel

    model: keyboardModel

    delegate: KeyButton {
        displayedText: model.display
        buttonId: model.id
    }
    onCountChanged:
    {
        console.log("Message")
    }
}
```

The problem is `console.log("Message")` calls twice, and i have no idea how it happens.

**P.S.** if i commented GridModel::loadModel() code console.log() is not called.

Comment: Where do you emit `countChanged`?

Comment: Count is a standart GridView property. As the result onCountChanged is standart slot and i don't need emit it anywhere. In my code i havn't line like this `emit GridView.CountChanged` and i dont connect to it. As i understood it calls automatically in `beginResetMode`/`endResetMode` block.

Comment: If i comment  line   `_elements = elements;` then there is only 1 call GridModel.onCountChanged

Comment: And if you comment: `_elements.clear()` instead?

Comment: In this case there are still 2 calls. (when `_elements = elements` not commented, but `_elements.clear()` commented.

Comment: Maybe the best would be, to extend your example, to be complete and verifyable, as the comments are not the right place to do debugging.

Comment: I would  just add more info in logs :
- add count value in QML message in onCountChanged
- add C++ logs at start and end of the loadModel method
This ways you'll see if either C++ function is called multiple times, or if resetting a models causes view to change count to (let say) 0 then N... (would not be that surprising in fact !)

Comment: https://gitlab.com/Nikxp/GridModel_count_updates_twice This is complete example. OnCountChanged works twice even if i called only "begin" and "end" without any changing in model (If model doesn't empty)!